# How to multiple a float number with an integer variable

Tags: c++

```
int dis1, dis2;
float sub1, sub2;
sub1 = dis1*(float)(5 / 100);
sub2 = dis2*(float)(5 / 100);
```

I got this code here. dis1 and dis2 are assigned int values by a CIN command. I don't understand why sub1 and sub2 become 0 after this, and what should I do to produce the result I want?

Comment: 5/100 is integer divison = 0 you should use 5.0/100.0

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thank you very much.